# Is there a way I can relate two object ID's in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Group` and `User` Schema, while `adding group` you map `users` to it. A `user` can belong to multiple `groups`.

I have a below `PartySchema` which has `user` and `groups`.

```
var Party = new Schema({
    name    : String,
    user: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }],
    groups: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }]
});
```

I am showing mapping in a `table structure` on like in a check-box in my `Party` page and selecting the group and its users for the "`Party`"

```
-- Groups
---- Users
```

You can select a group and its users in a `checkbox style[Parent[Group]-Children[User]]`. In the `PartySchema`, I am updating the selected `groups` and selected `users` respectively as `reference` and **not as a document.** in the `PartySchema`.

```
    user: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }],
    groups: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }]
```

I am just getting two `group` ids and `users` id, with this I am not able to say for `"Group1"` shane has been selected and not for `"Group2"`, because from earlier relationship "Shane" Belongs to two groups but while adding party I am selecting "shane" from Group2 only and not Group1.

While Editing the party page, I am getting all the Groups and Users again, in this I am not able to say "Shane" has been selected in Group2 as "Group1" also has "Shane" and "Group2" also has shane and we save it as a reference and not as a document.

```
-- Group1
---- Shane [Not selected]
-- Group1
---- Shane [selected]
```

Comment: ok instead of user list u need something like `user_group: [{user:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },group:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }}],` using `Schema.Types.Mixed`

Comment: just logic not sure if syntax is right though

Comment: @aishwatsingh: Wow... thanks a lot dude, so i would pass two object ids which are related to this array? can u show more details if u know?

Comment: i can , but i vl have to write some dummy code to get this up , possible for u to provide some ? i am not sure if this syntax vl work but approach seems ok. for time being this may help https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/

Comment: @aishwatsingh: I don't have any... i am just looking at the Schema.Types.Mixed but i don't know how to relate it...

Comment: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays/
in above link see how he defines `comments` in `PostSchema`

Answer (score 1):

**Party Schema**

```
 var Party = new Schema({
        name    : String,
        user_group: [{user:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },group:{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }}]
        groups: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }]
    });
```

---

**Party Object**

```
var party = new Party({
    name: "Haloween Party",
    user_group: [{
        user: shane._id,
        group: group1._id
    }, {
        user: userX._id,
        group: group1._id
    },
    {
        user: userY._id,
        group: group2._id
    }],
    groups:[group1._id,group2._id]
})
```

**Save Party and query for all existing Parties**

```
party.save(function(error) {
    if (!error) {
        Party.find({})
            .populate('user_group.user')
            .populate('user_group.group')
            .populate('groups')
            .exec(function(error, parties) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(parties, null, "\t"))//or just parties
            })
    }
});
```

**Party Document in db** *(something like this)*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e6"),
    "name" : "Haloween Party",
    "user_group" : [
        {
            "user" :  ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e5411"),
            "group" : ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e5"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e8")
        },
        {
            "user" :ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e5412"),
            "group" : ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e4"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e7")
        }
    ],
    "groups":[ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e5"),ObjectId("54cd6669d3e0fb1b302e54e4")]
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Git repo for a sample reference https://github.com/AlexZeitler/mongoose-schema-reference-sample